# Sequelize Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have 3 models, tags, books and likes.

Tags has many-to-many association with books and likes has one-to-many association with books.

I have query that selects books by tag name. Everything works fine until I wanna count book likes.

I added `[Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('book_likes.bookId')), 'likes']` but I get error - `Unknown column 'book_likes.bookId' in 'field list'`

```
const result = await Tags.findOne({
  subQuery: false,
  where: {
    name
  },
  attributes: ['name'],
  include: [
    {
      model: Book,
      attributes: [
        'title', 'image',
        [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('book_likes.bookId')), 'likes']
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: BookLikes,
          attributes: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  order: [
      [Books, 'createdAt', 'DESC']
  ],
});
```

Comment: Can you add the generated sql query?

Comment: Generated sql here https://pastebin.com/tdZK6wa9

Comment: Use an alias when including ```BookLikes``` Model like, ```as: "book_likes"```. Also, since it is an aliased column, instead of using ```sequelize.col()``` try using ```sequelize.literal()```

Comment: Using alias `as: "book_likes"` didn't work. Will try `sequelize.literal()`

Comment: Was trying with `[Sequelize.literal("COUNT(DISTINCT(book_likes.bookId))"), "bookLikeCount"]` but it didn't work either.

Comment: The issue might be, in generated query the alias is ```books->book_likes```, but the alias we are referring to in our query is ```book_likes```. This might be the issue think, try using sequelize literal with col name as ```books->book_likes.bookId```